# How can I conditionally add where clauses and filter children in a single linq query?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm using entity framework and building up a linq query so the query is executed at the database to minimize data coming back and the query can have some search criteria which is optional and some ordering which is done every time. I am working with parents and children (the mummy and daddy type). The filter I am trying to implement is for age of the children.

So if I have some data like so...

```
parent 1
- child[0].Age = 5
- child[1].Age = 10

parent 2
- child[0].Age = 7
- child[1].Age = 23
```

...and I specify a minimum age of 8, my intended result to display is...

```
parent 1
- child[1].Age = 10

parent 2
- child[1].Age = 23
```

...and if I specify a minimum age of 15 I intend to display...

```
parent 2
- child[1].Age = 23
```

I can re-create my expected result with this horrible query (which I assume is actually doing more than one query):

```
var parents = context.Parents;

if(minimumChildAge.HasValue)
{
    parents = parents.Where(parent => parent.Children.Any(child => child.Age >= minimumChildAge.Value));
    foreach(var parent in parents)
    {
        parent.Children = parent.Children.Where(child => child.minimumChildAge.Value >= mimumumChildAge);
    }
}

parents = parents.OrderBy(x => x.ParentId).Take(50);
```

So I tried the other method instead...

```
var query = from parent in context.Parents
            select parent;

if (minimumChildAge.HasValue)
    query = from parent in query
            join child in context.Children
            on parent.ParentId equals child.ParentId
            where child.Age >= minimumChildAge.Value
            select parent;

query = query.OrderBy(x => x.ParentId).Take(50);
```

When I run this in linqpad the query generated looks good. So my question...

Is this the correct way of doing this? Is there a better way? It seems a bit funny that if I now specified a maximum age that I would be writing the same joins and hoping that entity framework works it out. In addition, how does this impact lazy loading? I expect only the children which match the criteria to be returned. So when I do `parent.Children` does entity framework know that it just queried these and its working on a filtered collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your context is backed by an entity framework database or similar, then yes, your first option is going to do more than one SQL query. When you begin executing the `foreach` it will run a SQL query to get the parent (since you've forced enumeration on the query). Then, for each attempt to populate the `Children` property of a single parent object it will make another database call.

The second form should only produce a single SQL query; it will have a ton of redundant data but it will use `JOIN` statements to bring back all of the parent and child data in a single SQL call, then enumerate through it and populate the data on the client side as needed.

A rule of thumb I tend to follow is that, if you have fewer than 4 nested tables in your query, try to run it all at once. Both SQL and Entity Framework's query parsers seem to be very, very efficient when producing joins at that level.

If you get much beyond that, the SQL queries that EF can produce may get messy, and SQL itself (assuming MSSQL) gets less effective when you have 5+ joins on a single query. There's no hard and fast limit, because it depends on a number of specific factors, but if I find myself needing very deep nesting I tend to break it up into smaller LINQ queries and recombine them client-side.

(Side note: you can reproduce your second query in method syntax easily enough, since that's what the compiler is going to end up doing anyway, by using the `Join` method, but the syntax for that can get very complex; I typically go with query syntax for anything more complex then a single method call.)